# Is it possible to restrict access in Angular Routing for particular :ids in a path? Using Amplify/Cognito

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Say I have a routing module with the following setup:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: '', component: MainComponent,
  children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'dashboard/:id', component: DashboardComponent },
  {path: '404', component: HomeComponent},
   {path: '**', redirectTo: '/404'}
]
}];
```

Is it possible to restrict access to the following:

https://website.com/dashboard/1 (where only users who fall into 1 can see 1)
https://website.com/dashboard/2 (where only users who fall into 2 can see 2)

If a 1 goes to dashboard/2 they would be routed to an error page or vice versa. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the job of the [Guards](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate). You can implement `canActivate` function and pass to it preferable argument for the identification.

```
class UserToken {}
class Permissions {
  canActivate(user: UserToken, id: string): boolean {
    return true;
  }
}

@Injectable()
class CanActivateTeam implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private permissions: Permissions, private currentUser: UserToken) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean|UrlTree>|Promise<boolean|UrlTree>|boolean|UrlTree {
    return this.permissions.canActivate(this.currentUser, route.params.id);
  }
}
```

and after just configure your route with the guard:

```
{ path: 'dashboard/:id', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate:['Your Guard Name'] },
```

On successful authentication user will be able to continue. On fail you will implement redirect logic with angular `Router`.

Comment: Thank you! Not sure how I missed this doc.